# please guide me to covert the below code using joins

Tags: sql

```
select permission
from sharedUser
where userId = ?
  and folderId = (select folderId from folders where folderName = ?);
```

where,
folderId is a foreign key in sharedUser table and primary key in folders table.
permission and userId are just the normal columns in sharedUser table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT S.permission 
FROM sharedUser AS S 
JOIN FOLDERS AS F ON S.folderId =F.folderId 
 where S.userId = ? AND F.FOLDERNAME=?
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` might be needed, if a user has several folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT permission FROM sharedUser INNER JOIN folders on sharedUser.folderId = folders.id where folderName = 'xyz'
```